# is there way to get children from some index to some index in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having some records inside `<ul>`.like

```
<ul id="parent">
    <li> 1st record </li>
    <li> 2nd record </li>
    <li> 3rd record </li>
    <li> 4th record </li>
    // and so on
</ul>
<a href="#" id="loadMore"> Load More</a>
```

Initialy i have shown only 3 li elements to users now i have to show 3 more on each load more click. So i am looking something like `$('parent').children('li',3,6).show();` I have loaded all data at first ajax Call , but shown only 3 at first page load.

Comment: Do you want to show them or load them from a server?

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/slice/

Comment: So you want to show 6 on one click, and 9 on the second click, etc?

Comment: @putvande yes exactly.

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of jQuery's [`:lt(n)` selector](https://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/), which grabs the first `n` items.

If we narrow that selection down to [`:hidden`](https://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/) elements, it will incrementally show the next `n` elements each time.

```js
let resultsPerClick = 3;

$("#loadMore").click(function() {
  $("#parent li:hidden:lt(" + resultsPerClick + ")").show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="loadMore" Value="Load More" />

<ul id="parent">
    <li> 1st record </li>
    <li> 2nd record </li>
    <li> 3rd record </li>
    <li style="display: none;"> 4th record </li>
    <li style="display: none;"> 5 record </li>
    <li style="display: none;"> 6 record </li>
    <li style="display: none;"> 7 record </li>
    <li style="display: none;"> 8 record </li>
    <li style="display: none;"> 9 record </li>
    <li style="display: none;"> 10 record </li>
    <li style="display: none;"> 11 record </li>
    <li style="display: none;"> 12 record </li>
</ul>
```

```
$("#parent li:hidden")        //Grabs all of the hidden <li> elements
$("#parent li:lt(3)")         //Grabs the first three <li> elements
                              //Combine them...
$("#parent li:hidden:lt(3)")  //Grabs the first three hidden <li> elements
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has [`.slice( start [, end ] )`](https://api.jquery.com/slice/)

```
$('#parent').children('li').slice(3, 6).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```js
//show first 3
$("#parent").children("li").slice(0, 3).show();
$("a").on("click", function() {
  // grab 4th li
  var clicked = $("li:nth-child(4)").is(":visible");
  //check if visible
  if (clicked) {
    // if it is, show last 3
    $("li").slice(6, 9).show();
  } else {
    //if not, show second 3
    $("li").slice(3, 6).show();
  }
})
```

```css
#parent li {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="parent">
  <li> 1st record </li>
  <li> 2nd record </li>
  <li> 3rd record </li>
  <li> 4th record </li>
  <li> 5th record </li>
  <li> 6th record </li>
  <li> 7th record </li>
  <li> 8th record </li>
  <li> 9th record </li>
</ul>
<a href="#"> Load More</a>
```

Comment: This method may work for OP's example but will fail as soon as you add or remove items.

Comment: Nowhere OP states that scenario, one can speculate.